# Javascript Copy Object in chain style

Tags: javascript

I have a declared an Object something like below:

```
var seriesOptions = {
y: 99
};
```

In my code I keep creating adding new objects and add as a property to seriesOptions object :

```
drilldown = {
x: [90,20,40]
}
categories = {
z: [20,30,40.50]
}
values = {
p:[30,50,60]
}
```

Then:

```
seriesOptions['drilldown'] = drilldown
seriesOptions.drilldown['categories'] = categories;
seriesOptions.drilldown['values'] = values;
```

where drilldown, categories and values are another object

Now I have to copy try to copy seriesOptions object into another array **seriesOpts** like in a chain format

```
if(seriesOpts.length == 0)
     seriesOpts.push(seriesOptions);
else
     seriesOpts[seriesOpts.length - 1].drilldown = $.extend(true, {}, seriesOptions);
```

meaning that the new seriesOptions would be chained under last seriesOptions.drilldown object.

My issue is that I am not able to see the seriesOptions.y value in

> seriesOpts[seriesOpts.length - 1].drilldown

object? I am expecting something like below:

> seriesOpts[x].y : 99
>
> seriesOpts[x].drilldown.y : 99

Please let me know what wrong I am doing in my code?

Note I am using $.extend to copy the object to new one. So how can I retain both old and new values like :  seriesOpts[x].y and seriesOpts[x].drilldown.y are accessible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right before `if(seriesOpts.length == 0)` do a `console.log(seriesOpts.length)` because seriesOpts is defined as object and length might include prototype functions.

Comment: console.log shows correct value at that level

Comment: `seriesOpts` will only ever have length 0 or 1, it will never go beyond since if length is 1, then `seriesOpts[0].drilldown` is relpaced by a new "extended" object. And there will never be more than one `seriesOpts[0].drilldown.drilldown`. So you can only ever access `seriesOpts[0].y` after the first iteration and `seriesOpts[0].drilldown.y` after all subsequent (2+) iterations.

Comment: Firebug does not shows me `seriesOpts[0].drilldown.y`value. It only shows me `seriesOpts[0].y` value  - when I do console logging as **console.log(seriesOpts)**. Please let me know if I am missing something you wanted to state

Answer (score 0):

I think this `else` block is wrong

```
$.extend(true, {}, seriesOptions);
```

It should use this

```
$.extend(true, {}, seriesOptions.drilldown);
```